# Limit test for series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

The limit comparison test requires that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positive. What is an example of  series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$ but $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum b_n$ does not?

Comment: If the limit of the ratio is $1$, then $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ is either *converges* or *diverges*. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test. Do you mean you want to find an example when $\lim_n a_n/b_n = 0$ ?

Comment: I think OP wants an example showing that the assumptions that $a_n, b_n > 0$ really matters.

Comment: I think it's a good question; I hadn't really thought about it much.  If the limit is $1$, then in the long run $a_n \approx b_n$, so it seems that they are either eventually both positive or both negative.

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn the theorem you referred to requires that $a_n, b_n > 0$. Does the same hold even though $a_n, b_n$ are not always positive or there is a counterexample?